# GCM Notification onclick does not open specified activity

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, gcmlistenerservice

None of previoues asked questions solve my problem unfortunately. My application insists to does not open specified activity. Instead it opens main activity which is GCMService.java

```
private void sendNotification(String message) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LaunchActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 , intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle("GCM Message")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Following is my LaunchActivity definition and GCMService activity definitons in android manifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".LaunchActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_launch"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    android:exported="true"
    android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".GCMService"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove this _<intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>_ from **LaunchActivity** from manifest file.

Comment: Does _GCMService_ class extend with _Activity_?

Comment: Extends from AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 0):

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, LaunchActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```